# I have problem with class that creates rectangle based on a test

Tags: java, constructor, rectangles

Ok so i have rectangle that should be created based on: method point that will crete coordinates of it center and values of hight and width, all value are based on this test

```
public void testRectangle1() {
        Point center = new Point(20, 30);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(center, 20, 20);
        assertAll(
                () -> assertEquals(10, rect.getTopLeft().getX()),
                () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getTopLeft().getY()),
                () -> assertEquals(30, rect.getBottomRight().getX()),
                () -> assertEquals(40, rect.getBottomRight().getY()),
                () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getWidth()),
                () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getHeight())
        );
    }
```

I have prewritten class point that i will add here for overall clarity

```
package net.thumbtack.school.figures.v1;

public class Point {

    private int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void moveTo(int newX, int newY) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }

    public void moveRel(int dx, int dy) {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is class for creating rectangle

```
package net.thumbtack.school.figures.v1;

public class Rectangle {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public Point center;
    public int xCenter;
    public int yCenter;
    private Point point;



    public Rectangle(Point center, int width, int height) {
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
        this.center=center;
    }


    public Point getTopLeft() {
        Point point = getCenter();
        point.moveRel(- width / 2, - height / 2);
        return point;
    }

    public Point getBottomRight() {
        Point point = getCenter();
        point.moveRel(width / 2,  height / 2);
        return point;
    }

    public int getWidth() {

        return width;
    }


    public int getHeight() {

        return height;
    }

    public Point getCenter() {
       Point center = new Point(xCenter, yCenter);
       return center;
    }
```

So problem is in constructor  `public Rectangle(Point center, int width, int height)` when i run the test it returns wirng values

expected: <10> but was: <-10>
Comparison Failure:
Expected :10
Actual   :-10

expected: <20> but was: <-10>
Comparison Failure:
Expected :20
Actual   :-10

expected: <30> but was: <10>
Comparison Failure:
Expected :30
Actual   :10

expected: <40> but was: <10>
Comparison Failure:
Expected :40
Actual   :10

I dont this that the problem is into other methods becouse when i use them in different but simmilar constrictors everything works.

Comment: From within your `Rectangle` methods you call `getCenter()`, which passes `xCenter` and `yCenter`. These have never been initialized correctly as far as I can tell. So that might be why you get wrong results.

Comment: Off topic somewhat, however what happens when you put the centre of your rectangle at positions 3,3 or say positions 11,11, is the answer still correct for getTopLeft and getBottomRight? Depending on your requirements it might be, but if I were you, I would add tests for odd valued coordinates and size. Also given your point class has an equals method, you could assert against point rather than the components of points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As maloomeister mentioned you must init `xCenter` or `yCenter` before used，or the value of `xCenter` and `yCenter` is 0.

modify `getCenter()` method:

```
public Point getCenter() {
    Point point = new Point(center.getX(), center.getY());
    return point;
}
```

Comment: I would go further and remove `xCenter` and `yCenter` and just add/keep `center`.  It is error prone and requires more effort to maintain two version of the same information, as you will have to keep them in sync with each other through out the code.

Comment: @Gavin  yes  `xCenter` and `yCenter ` not needed